# Получение удаленной строки в DataView

Tags: c#

Сразу оговорюсь, в **table** строки **не удаляем**, мы просто меняем данные. Если поменяли данные в колонке **col1**, то происходит событие удаления во **view**

```
DataTable table = /*Чего-нибудь*/;
DataView view = new DataView(table) { RowFilter = "col1 = 123" };
view.ListChanged += delegate(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e) 
{
  if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
  {
    //Как тут получить удаленную строку???
  }
}
```

вопрос как получить эту строку.

PS. Мне все равно в каком виде её получить, либо **DataRow**, либо **DataRowView**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Блин! только так... Спасибо [Alexander Petrov](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/184217/alexander-petrov) за [Подсказку](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455128/185848)

```
private System.Data.DataView InitializeDataView(System.Data.DataTable table, string rowFilter)
{
  System.Data.DataView view = new System.Data.DataView(table);
  m_DataRowViewIndexes[view] = new List<System.Data.DataRow>();
  view.ListChanged += ListChanged;
  view.RowFilter = rowFilter; //Обязательно после подписки события
  return view;
}
private Dictionary<System.Data.DataView, List<System.Data.DataRow>> m_DataRowViewIndexes = new Dictionary<System.Data.DataView, List<System.Data.DataRow>>();
private void ListChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
  System.Data.DataView view = sender as System.Data.DataView;
  if (view != null)
    switch (e.ListChangedType)
    {
      case System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.Reset:
        m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].Clear();
        foreach (System.Data.DataRowView row in view)
          m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].Add(row.Row);
        break;
      case System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemMoved:
        System.Data.DataRow item = m_DataRowViewIndexes[view][e.OldIndex];
        m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].RemoveAt(e.OldIndex);
        m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].Insert(e.NewIndex, item);
        break;
      case System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemDeleted:
        System.Data.DataRow delItem = m_DataRowViewIndexes[view][e.NewIndex];
        //delItem <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  Мы удалили эту строку !!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
        m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].RemoveAt(e.NewIndex);
        break;
      case System.ComponentModel.ListChangedType.ItemAdded:
        m_DataRowViewIndexes[view].Insert(e.NewIndex, view[e.NewIndex].Row);
        break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Фильтр не удаляет строку. Он ее скрывает.
Удаляет явный метод Delete(IndexOfRow) <--- а индекс известен.

```
static void table_RowDeleting(object sender, DataRowChangeEventArgs e)
{
    // а тут уже работай с удаленной строкой e.Row (DataRow)
}

static void view_ListChanged(object sender, ListChangedEventArgs e)
{
    Console.WriteLine(e.ListChangedType);
    if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ItemDeleted");
        Console.WriteLine(e.OldIndex);
        Console.WriteLine(e.NewIndex);
    }
}

private static void PrintDataView(DataView dv)
{
    foreach (DataRowView drv in dv)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("\t {0}", drv["NAME"]);
    }
}

[STAThread]
static void Main()
{
    DataTable table = new DataTable();
    table.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[] { new DataColumn("ID", typeof(int)), new DataColumn("NAME", typeof(string)) } );
    table.Rows.Add(1, "one");
    table.Rows.Add(2, "two");
    table.Rows.Add(3, "three");
    DataView view = new DataView(table);
    table.RowDeleting += table_RowDeleting;
    view.ListChanged+=view_ListChanged;
    // начальный вид
    PrintDataView(view);
    // применим фильтр
    view.RowFilter = "ID <> 2";
    PrintDataView(view);
    // отменим фильтр, строки живы
    view.RowFilter = "";
    PrintDataView(view);
    // а теперь удаляем известный индекс

    view.Delete(0);
    // и соответственно
    PrintDataView(view);

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: Это всё хорошо, но вы не ответили на вопрос автора: как ему получить строку, автоматически удаляемую из DataView при несовпадении введённых данных с фильтром?

Comment: Как же не удаляет, а Вам **if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)** не о чем не говорит??? Я про DataView.

Comment: Тем более индекс "удаляемой" строки **из DataView** известен! Неизвестен удаляемый элемент, т.е. **DataRowView**, или его **DataRow**!

Comment: мне трудно понять такие изыски. можно конечно дублировать строки, но для этого есть DataТable. И селекты там аналогичные, и вообще сам класс называется соответственно. DataView это вьюшка - отображение. Работай с данными в Табле, а отображай во вьюшке

Answer (score 1):

Можно отслеживать событие DataTable.RowChanged.

```
table.RowChanged += (o, e) =>
{
    // e.Row - изменённая строка
};
```

То есть привязка GUI по-прежнему будет к DataView, но изменения будут также отражаться в DataTable.

---

Попробуйте такой способ. Сперва создаём коллекцию с начальным набором строк, попавших в DataView:

```
DataView view = new DataView(table) { RowFilter = "col1 = 123" };
var rowHashSet = new HashSet<DataRowView>(view.OfType<DataRowView>());
```

Затем в обработчике события находим удалённую строку, сравнив предыдущий набор строк с текущим. После чего удаляем эту строку и из HashSet'а.

```
if (e.ListChangedType == ListChangedType.ItemDeleted)
{
    var diff = rowHashSet.Except(view.OfType<DataRowView>());
    var deletedRow = diff.First(); // искомая строка
    rowHashSet.Remove(deletedRow);                    
}
```

При этом нужно не забыть добавлять строки в HashSet, если они каким-либо образом попадают в DataView в процессе работы.

И при каждом изменении фильтра нужно заново наполнять HashSet.

Comment: А если фильтр неизвестен, или постоянно меняется? Мне нужно именно события удаления строки из вьюшки.

Comment: @ДмитрийЧистик - Обновил ответ.

Comment: Меня Ваш ответ натолкнул на решение! Решение представлено [ниже](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/455259/185848).